# Result of ls contains folders with empty names

Tags: linux, ls

The IT guys in my company grant me permissions so that I can ssh onto a server.

However when I invoked command `ls -alh /` it shows:
[image: Root]

As you can see there are many directories shown with empty names (except for those with permission `rwxrwxrwt`). This also happens in my home folder:
[image: Home folder]

Another weird thing is I can `cd` to one of the "hidden" folders like `/mnt` even if I can't "see" it.

In what condition could this happen? Is my permission set incorrectly by IT guys?

Comment: Are you sure the names are not shown? Maybe you have a problem with your color palette instead. If you copy & paste from the terminal into an editor, are the names still missing?

Comment: looks indeed like a color palette issue; look at the color of the text of your "/tmp" folder...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely, `ls` is aliased in such way that it is invoked as `ls --color` which somehow messes with terminal settings. You may list all aliases by running `alias`. Your options:

1. Run ls as `ls -alh --color=none`
2. Remove alias (affects current session only): `unalias ls`

Comment: @ypnos Thanks guys, you're right - somehow the LS_COLORS is set inappropriately on server's .bashrc, thus the color of directory name becomes the same as the background color of my terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Change the terminal color scheme of the terminal you are using to connect to the ssh box.